# firebase.messaging().getInitialNotification() does not work on android(when app is killed)

Tags: android, react-native, firebase-cloud-messaging

So, I have migrated Firebase on my project from v@5 to v@14 because push-notifications did not work on android API31+(v12) at all.

*NOTE: we use `react-native-splash-screen`. Folk pointed out on some problems [react-native-firebase/issues/4005](https://github.com/invertase/react-native-firebase/issues/4005) and [react-native-firebase/issues/2768](https://github.com/invertase/react-native-firebase/issues/2768) and [react-native-splash-screen/issues/289](https://github.com/crazycodeboy/react-native-splash-screen/issues/289) and suggested to move from older splash approach to `react-native-bootsplash` as an alternatiove, which was not really the solution for us.
PS. any comments inside links above did not help*

`firebase.messaging().onNotificationOpenedApp` - Unlike initial pushes, in background mode push service was performing well as expected.

Answer (score 1):

**My problem was resolved by using API from 3d-party library such `react-native-push-notification` instead of `firebase.messaging().getInitialNotification()`.**

```
const getAndroidInitialNotification = (remoteMessage: ReceivedNotification | null): void => {
  const data = remoteMessage?.data;

  if (data) {
     // Your code such deep links implementation, dispatch to reducer etc...
  }
};

PushService.popInitialNotification(handleInitialNotifications);
```

Hope this will help for somebody like me, who do not understand what is the affection of **splash approach** on firebase service and all related confusing stuff.